# best way to use indent/javascript.vim within indent/html.vim for <script> tags

Tags: vim

what's the best way to use indent/javascript.vim within indent/html.vim for  tags

Edit:
Appologies, as suggested I should really give a little more to go on so that you can help.

My vim settings can be found https://github.com/davetayls/vim-settings

I'm currently using html.vim from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2075
I'm using javascript.vim from http://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript

Both of these are working really well for their prospective file types.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 4):

What is the problem you are trying to solve? What doesn't work? What does?

You can tell Vim this file is an HTML+JS file (and thus take advantage of both language-specific sets of features) by issuing this command:

```
set filetype=html.javascript
```

If you are not satisfied with the default indent files you can search for a better one on [the Vim website](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=javascript&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search).

Someone has [ported](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075) a cool Emacs feature called "narrowing" over to Vim. I've used it to  debug large `<style></style>` and `<script></script>` portions in an old project. It's very nice.

I'll probably get a downvote but you should write your JavaScript in a separate `*.js` file. The benefits of doing this go well beyond fixing indentation problems in your editor (separation of concern, focus, maintainability, loading order, loading time…).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response...yes on the whole i use a separate js file. it's when i'm doing something small or tests that i use the script tag. essentially i have a better html.vim and javascript.vim indent than the built in ones but the html.vim doesn't use the javascript.vim to format inside script tags

Comment: OK, did you try `set filetype=html.javascript`?

Comment: There's no way to infer from your question that you use some other scripts than the default ones. Please consider adding some details to your question (what works, what doesn't, short script samples…) and the URLs of your better indent scripts. The `set ft=html.javascript` trick works perfectly here with the stock indent scripts.

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question above to help hopefully. thanks for your help